# Redirect not reference url

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have a system that generate some url like `system?hash=abcdef01223456789`
This url refer me to the one site:

> site.com

I want do something in `site.com`, to make it open only from `system?hash=abcdef`
this site redirects to `site.com`
Don't want open it in `site.com` (I know about some php variables to get reference url, but need same in js)
And don't want to open it with `bit.ly/12345/` or something like this. Only with my system. How can I do it in js? Is it possible?

Comment: your question is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can check from javascript on page load like :

```
 var field = 'hash';
    var url = window.location.href;
    if(url.indexOf('?' + field + '=') != -1)
        return true;
```